# IPv6 Token for Windows

Tags: ipv6

I am try to figure out, how I can set a fixed Interface Identifier on Windows.

On Linux we can set it as example with:

- NetworkManager

  ```
  $ nmcli connection modify MYWIFI ipv6.token "::1:1:1:1"
  ```

  From the [manual](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/settings-ipv6.html):
  Configure the token for draft-chown-6man-tokenised-ipv6-identifiers-02 IPv6 tokenized interface identifiers. Useful with eui64 addr-gen-mode.
- systemd-networkd

  ```
  $ cat /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network
  [Match]
  Name=eth0

  [Network]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  DHCP=yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  IPv6Token=::1:1:1:1
  ```

  From the [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html): An IPv6 address with the top 64 bits unset. When set, indicates the 64-bit interface part of SLAAC IPv6 addresses for this link. Note that the token is only ever used for SLAAC, and not for DHCPv6 addresses, even in the case DHCP is requested by router advertisement. By default, the token is autogenerated.

But how can we arrive the same on Windows? A fixed Address is not the Solution, because my ISP change the Global/Subnet ID part sometimes.

Also it would be fine, to have more ipv6 Addresses, like on Linux. There I have the fixed address (with the Token) and the usual ipv6 privacy extension address, which is used for outgoing requests.

Comment: I think you may mean `IPv6 Prefix Delegation`.

Comment: no, this is not what I am locking for. The prefix is deployed from my router. I want to set the interface identifier

Comment: Right, You want the IID to remain the same, regardless of the prefix assigned by the ISP. In other words, IPv6 Prefix Delegation.

Comment: and how I can do it? So I can check if it is what I want

Comment: but I think we not talk about the same thing. The prefix is deployed by SLAAC or dhcpv6. The Host itself adds the interface id - that's what I understand

Comment: I also added some more infos to my Linux examples

Comment: I don't think Windows actually supports this. You can search Microsoft TechNet, but it sounds like may be stuck.